# SBT publishing snapshots to sonatype

Tags: sbt, release, sonatype, sbt-release

I am working on a project and the source got open sourced and we've decided to publish to maven central.
https://github.com/mdsol/mauth-java-client/tree/refactor/publish_to_sonatype

Currently we are publishing to an internal repo and it allows publishing of SNAPSHOTS with timestamps so we can publish multiple time the same snapshot version. However, it looks like sonatype doesn't allow uploading with timestamps or overwriting.

How do I delete existing snapshot of sonatype so new one can be published as part of the sbt build?  Also, do I `sonatypeRelease` the snapshots?

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a Sonatype account, and then log in via their web front-end: https://oss.sonatype.org/

Once you did a `sbt publishSigned`, for example, you can then search for your package in the (staging) repositories and, if you are indeed logged in while doing that, delete or release it. (I found that `sbt sonatypeRelease` did not reliably release my package. So I ended up using their web front-end exclusively for the latter.)

This is outlined, more or less, also in the official sbt documentation:
https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Using-Sonatype.html#Third+-+Publish+to+the+staging+repository